# matplotlib - colouring by values of an array

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm struggling in plotting scattered points which are coloured by a value from a list (for simplicity here the color shall be the y-value). I'm somehow succeeding, but it seems, that only the last read in values are recognised for the colouring. My code by now

```
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("test_a") as fobj:
    first_line = fobj.readline()
    nbnd = re.findall('\d+', first_line )[0]
    nks = re.findall('\d+', first_line )[1]
    nbnd = int(nbnd)
    nks = int(nks)
    all_values = iter(x for x in fobj.read().split())
    ek = []
    kpt = []
    for x in range(nks):
        kpt.append([float(next(all_values)) for counter in range(3)])
        ek.append([float(next(all_values)) for counter in range(nbnd)])

X = []
Y = []
for j in range(len(kpt)):
   X.append(kpt[j][0]+kpt[j][1]+kpt[j][2])
Y = np.array(ek)


for i in range(len(ek[0])):
    p1 = plt.scatter(X, [pt[i] for pt in Y], c = [pt[i] for pt in Y] , s = 100,  marker = "o", edgecolors= "none")
plt.colorbar(p1)
plt.show()
```

and a simple test_data:

```
&pl nd=  6, ns=   4 /
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.000000 
    -5 -5 -5.1 -5.23 -5.4 -5.4
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.100000 
    -4 -4 -6.1 -6 -5.4 -6
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.200000 
    -2 -2.1 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -2.0
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.300000 
    -1.1 1.2 1.5 1.55 1.2 2.0
```

new test_data:

```
&pl nd=  6, ns=   4 /
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.000000 
    -5 -5 -5.1 -5.23 -5.4 -9.4
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.100000 
    -4 -4 -6.1 -6 -5.4 -8
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.200000 
    -2 -2.1 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -2.0
    -0.500000 -0.288675  0.300000 
    -2.1 1.2 1.5 1.55 1.2 2.0
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing something up with the for-loop, when assigning the color, but I can't see why/where...

[image: resulting plot]

EDIT: It was a rather stupid error, the colorbar was not arranged properly while looping through the data. Setting the extremal limits solved the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("test_a") as fobj:
    first_line = fobj.readline()
    nbnd = re.findall('\d+', first_line )[0]
    nks = re.findall('\d+', first_line )[1]
    nbnd = int(nbnd)
    nks = int(nks)
    all_values = iter(x for x in fobj.read().split())
    ek = []
    kpt = []
    for x in range(nks):
        kpt.append([float(next(all_values)) for counter in range(3)])
        ek.append([float(next(all_values)) for counter in range(nbnd)])

X = []
Y = []
for j in range(len(kpt)):
   X.append(kpt[j][0]+kpt[j][1]+kpt[j][2])
Y = np.array(ek)

#find extrema
vmin = np.amin(Y)
vmax = np.amax(Y)

for i in range(len(ek[0])):
    p1 = plt.scatter(X, [pt[i] for pt in Y], c = [pt[i] for pt in Y] , s = 100,  marker = "o", edgecolors= "none", vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.colorbar(p1)
plt.show()
```

[image: new resulting plot]

Comment: Your code runs fine for me and generates [this](https://imgur.com/a/pVgyJxk) image

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Yes it generates the same figure for me, but I feel the color-values do not correspond to the y-values. I've put a better data-set, the first one wasn't that wisely chosen. With the new set I get following figure: https://imgur.com/vQPxxHY Obviously the red framed dots should have similar color, which isn't the case.

Comment: Problem solved. The colorbar wasn't arranged properly. Post was edited.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if other people are going to read your code, you might want variable names more explicit than `kpt` and `ek` unless they are known acronyms in your field.